# How to allow an external system to update a field on quote object after a callout

Tags: apex, callout, webservices, apex-webservice

I have a question please ,i did a callout (Rest) to an externel system ,i send some informations of a quote record ,when the response is ok ,the external system will update a custom field in my quote .

I want to know how can i allow the external system to do  this update in the my quote Object ?

When i send the callout ,i get just Ok as a response ,after 3 days ,the external system will update a field in my object Quote .
My question now ,how this external system will be allowed to do this action ? what kind of information i need to provide it to be allowed to update a field in a standard object in salesforce (Quote)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide more information , I am assuming you want to update based on response received from external system (JSON) and update your quote record.

Comment: I will clarify more my question :i send a callout to the external system ,i receive  just ok from the external system .
After 3 days ,the external system will update a field in my quote object .
my question ,how this external system will be allowed to do this action ? what kind of information i need to provide the external system to be allowed to update a field in standard object in salesforce (Quote)

Comment: You need to create a class and expose it as rest resource (http post) which an external system can hit with predefined parameters and you can make update to quote object.
You will also need to take care of authentication using connected app which will validate external party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a part of the call to the external system you need to send it the id or some other unique external id field.

The external system can then make a call to either Rest or SOAP Salesforce API or an Apex method exposed as a Rest resource or Webservice to make the update using the unique field sent to it in the first call.